# Is std::common_type buggy under VC10 compiler?

Tags: c++

This code prints out "unsigned short" for both checks under VC11, but the first check prints "int" under VC10. I would always expect `std::common_type<T,T>::type` to be `T`. Is this a bug or allowed behaviour? Perhaps the behaviour changed between between VC10's implementation and the final C++11 standard?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    unsigned short a = 1;
    unsigned short b = 2;
    auto c = true ? a : b;
    std::cout << typeid(std::common_type<unsigned short, unsigned short>::type).name() << std::endl; // VC10: int
    std::cout << typeid(c).name() << std::endl; // VC10: unsigned short
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For sure it did not change from C++03 because it was only added in C++11.

Comment: @jrok But it easily could have changed with respect to an earlier draft.  Logically, one would expect (and want) `int`, but the wording in C++11 definitely says `unsigned short`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Where does it say that?

Comment: @jrok: Excellent point! I'll change the question to make me look less stupid!

Comment: @JamesKanze: Actually I was expecting `unsigned short` since that's what both types are... Using `common_type` as a return type for some operation gives warnings about conversions in VC10 because it's turning things into `int`s when I would prefer it not to.

Comment: @jrok **§20.9.7.6,3** defines `common_type` for two parameters as  `decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>())`, and **§5.16,6** (about `?:`) says that "the usual arithmetic conversions are applied to bring them to a common type", which is `unsigned short`

Comment: Do you have access to `common_type`'s implementation source code (headers) for VC10 and/or VC11? Otherwise, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type suggests that it _might_ be implemented with a conditional expression, so you can test something like `unsigned short a, b; cout << typeid(true?a:b).name()` or `typedef unsigned short us; cout << typeid(true?us():us()).name()` on both compiler versions and see if they differ (maybe VC10 was promoting `unsigned short` to `int`)

Comment: Indeed! I've just been coding a test to see the differences between how `common_type` and the ternary operator deduce types. It definitely looks broken in VC10.

Comment: Just added some more example code. This is broken. If anyone wants to answer with "yes" I'll accept it :)

Comment: @jrok In the standard:-).  Seriously, it is `decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>()`, which sends us to the `?:` operator.  Where, once you get through upteen cases which don't apply, you end up with "The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type."  Only if that doesn't hold do you get to the following point, which is the usual arithmetic conversions, which start with integral promotion.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, thank you. I found it myself in the mean time :)

Comment: @BenHymers I would normally have expected the type which would result if I used a binary operator (like `+`) on it.  (But of course, not all pairs of types support `+`.)  Since in his case, `a + b` has type `int`, I would have expected `common_type( decltype(a), decltype(b) )` to have type `int`.

Comment: @JamesKanze - common_type is not meant to evaluate to the type of an arithmetic expression, it's meant to be a library replacement for the ternary operator with specializations for other library types (i.e. duration). auto is typically sufficient for the expression type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's buggy. std::common_type is a hack in VC10 that uses type promotion such that anything with a `sizeof` less than `sizeof(int)` is promoted to `int`:

```
std::_Ipromo<unsigned short>::_Type _PromoTy0;

_PromoTy0 is an int.
```

Comment: Nasty! Thanks for checking the implementation! Yet another reason for me to recommend upgrading from VC10...

Comment: Occasionally I get called on to look at/work on a project that is still using VC10 and it makes me a little sad. But at least nobody has asked me to look at a VC6 project in a while :/